# Neo4j Cypher extend the query to return supplemental info

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (root:Location) 
WHERE root.id IN $locationIds
WITH root 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root) 
WITH COLLECT(root.id) AS listRoot, COLLECT(DISTINCT ascendant.id) AS listAscendant, COLLECT(DISTINCT descendant.id) AS listDescendant 
WITH listDescendant + listRoot + listAscendant AS dadLocationIds
WITH dadLocationIds 
WITH apoc.coll.intersection(dadLocationIds, [60, 58]) as output
UNWIND output AS locationId
RETURN locationId
```

Is it possible to extend this query in order to not only return the intersected `locationId`, but also for each `locationId` return the corresponding `ID from $locationIds` and also the mark(how it was matched) - `direct`, `ascendant`, `descendant`.

For example:

```
locationId | id from $locationIds | mark
-------------------------------------------------
1          | 12                   | ascendant
5          | 4                    | descendant
8          | 8                    | direct
```

**UPDATED**

I test the query provided in the answer.

As an input I use the following Locations:

```
╒══════╤════════╕
│"l.id"│"l.name"│
╞══════╪════════╡
│110   │"USA"   │
├──────┼────────┤
│111   │"Europe"│
├──────┼────────┤
│112   │"Poland"│
├──────┼────────┤
│113   │"Warsaw"│
└──────┴────────┘
```

were there is the following hierarchy:

```
USA
Europe->Poland->Warsaw
```

I execute the following query:

```
MATCH (root:Location) 
WHERE root.id IN[111,112]
WITH root 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(descendant:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*0..]->(root) 
WITH COLLECT({id: root.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'direct'}) AS listRoot, COLLECT(DISTINCT {id: ascendant.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'ascendant'}) AS listAscendant, COLLECT(DISTINCT {id: descendant.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'descendant'}) AS listDescendant 
WITH listDescendant + listRoot + listAscendant AS dadLocationIds
WITH [locId in dadLocationIds where locId.id in [110, 112] | locId]  as output
UNWIND output as out  
WITH DISTINCT out.id AS locationId, out.rootId as rootId, out.mark as mark
RETURN locationId, rootId, mark
```

and the result is:

```
╒════════════╤════════╤════════════╕
│"locationId"│"rootId"│"mark"      │
╞════════════╪════════╪════════════╡
│112         │111     │"descendant"│
├────────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│112         │112     │"descendant"│
├────────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│112         │112     │"direct"    │
├────────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│112         │112     │"ascendant" │
└────────────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

looks like something wrong for 112:112

Comment: How is locationId 8 a direct match for 15?

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, my bad - it should be 8-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query that will work for you.

```
MATCH (root:Location) 
WHERE root.id IN $locationIds
WITH root 
OPTIONAL MATCH (root)-[:CONTAINS*1..]->(descendant:Location) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ascendant:Location)-[:CONTAINS*1..]->(root) 
// create a map of rootId, ascendant and descendant ids and marking
WITH COLLECT({id: root.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'direct'}) AS listRoot, COLLECT(DISTINCT {id: ascendant.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'ascendant'}) AS listAscendant, COLLECT(DISTINCT {id: descendant.id, rootId: root.id, mark: 'descendant'}) AS listDescendant 
WITH listDescendant + listRoot + listAscendant AS dadLocationIds
// filter dadlocationids instead of using APOC intersection
WITH [locId in dadLocationIds where locId.id in [60, 58] | locId]  as output
// unwind each record
UNWIND output as out 
// parse the mapping per column  
WITH out.id AS locationId, out.rootId as rootId, out.mark as mark
RETURN locationId, rootId, mark
```

Below is my sample output:

```
╒════════════╤════════╤════════════╕
│"locationId"│"rootId"│"mark"      │
╞════════════╪════════╪════════════╡
│1           │8       │"ascendant" │
├────────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│2           │9       │"descendant"│
├────────────┼────────┼────────────┤
│7           │7       │"root"      │
└────────────┴────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you! I try to execute query but it fails with the `Invalid input 'direct': expected "YIELD" or an identifier (line 7, column 50 (offset: 228))`

Comment: For some reason my Neo4j doesn't understand this construction `mark: 'direct'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to escape the single qoute.  Use this one:   mark: \'direct\'

Comment: the same result ( I try the query directly on the Neo4j Browser

Comment: found the reason! {} missed in this line

Comment: youre right! good catch

Comment: Could you please take a look into updated question?

Comment: CONTAINS*0  means getting no relationship is okey. Thus root is repeated twice from ascendant and descendant.  Please use CONTAINS*1.. instead

Comment: Thank You very much ! Looks like this is working now as expected!! Thanks!

Comment: Excellent! Glad that it worked for you!